# How to create a web component with vuetify

Tags: vue.js, web, vuetify.js, web-component

I've built a component in my vue + vuetify app and I want to make a web component out of it.

I managed to include vue and vuetify in the package, but the style, icons included, still isn't working in the shadow dom(which, actually, is a huge part of vuetify).

The component has to work without access to the internet.

I'm building the package with the following command:

```
vue-cli-service build --target wc --name <name> <component> --inline-vue
```

What should I do?
Thank you!